# Formulas not updating when macro changes sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to change a sheet name depending on what a user inputs. This works fine, my problem is that usually when you change a sheet name manually, the formulas that relate to the changed sheet all update.

This isn't happening when the macro changes the sheet name. Is there anything I can do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Since the sheet you are renaming is not the active sheet, you will need to reference the new sheet in your macro. Try this:

`Sheets(NewName2).EnableCalculation = False

Sheets(NewName2).EnableCalculation = True`

Comment: I tried that and couldn't get it to work - is this what you meant?

`code` 

Sub Rename()
'

'
    NewName2 = InputBox("Enter New Client Abbreviation?")
    Sheets("New Performance (2)").Name = NewName2
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

`code`

Comment: Is the sheet you are renaming the active sheet when you run the macro? That may affect the outcome. Answered edited with another possible solution.

Comment: Hi - no it's not active. The user clicks on a button in another sheet and it asks what they want to call the sheet. When they click ok it updates the specified sheet. I can't see how to Thanks

Comment: I've just had another look and the problem actually occurs just before this stage. The sheets that are not updating formulas are created by duplicating two existing sheets. It is at this point that the formulas are not updating.

The code I have used for this is - `code` Sheets("New Performance").Select
Sheets("New Performance").Copy After:=Sheets(7) `code` I tried your code above and changed the sheet name to New Performance (2) which is what the new sheet is called but this doesn't work?? Thanks so much for your help with his!! :)

Comment: Happy to help! Hmmm... Did you use quotation marks? `Sheets("SheetName")` Otherwise, I think we would need to see your code to find the issue.

Comment: I didn't!! But I've just tried again with the SheetName in quotes and it still doesn't change :(

Answer (score 0):

So I do this with formulas/advanced lookups embedded in a template sheet using the following two-step process:

```
            Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'this is putting it at the very end of my document based upon the count of tabs
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = sName ' we then rename the sheet, because you want it created, then you want to rename it, as it will then allow for all formulas to refresh.
```

Comment: Did you try the above solution? Seemed the below was not resolving your issue.